# Not allowed to load local resource in MAUI Blazor

Tags: android, html, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I'm trying to set a local resource as an image source in Html, but I get this eror in console:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///sdcard/0.jpg

I'm using Android platform and MAUI Blazor.

Comment: How are you hosting your application?  I assume not by opening an html file locally.  It would be a serious security vulnerablility if a web site could just read arbitrary files on a user's device, which is why that is not allowed.

Comment: It's an internal webhost, which is running inside the Android app I guess.

Comment: If you're not loading the web page using `file:///` then references using that protocol will fail.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this?